# How to set Action bar sherlock color permenent through java?

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

I want to change the ActionBarSherlock color permanently, I tried the following code but, when I reopen the application it resets to the previous color

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
```

My intentions are to make a theme that changes the ActionBarSherlock color with user input

Comment: can you please elaborate on this, so you are able to change color to your preferred type, but your problem is it always resets what you had previously? so what then did you want? you can call that line of code in your oncreate always and it will seem permanent

Answer (score -1):

First of all, stop using ActionBarSherlock. Use the `AppCompat` library provided by Android.

Secondly use [ActionBar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) to apply style (color) to the ActionBar

Comment: Can you please explain why should the OP avoid using `ActionBarSherlock`? Are there any issues with it?

Comment: `ActionBarCompat` provides better integration with some other functionalities such as Navigation Drawer. This project is by Google, is part of the Support Library and thus likely will support new Action Bar related stuff at the same time Google releases them with stock Android.

The creator of `ActionBarSherlock`, Jake Wharton, announced on Google+ that further development of `ActionBarSherlock` has been stopped. `ActionBarSherlock 4.4` is the last release  – but there won’t be any new features:

Comment: Sir, i feel you are to answer the question not give your personal opinion on it. and secondly `ActionBar` is deprecated so? if you want to suggest why not use comment? and why not suggest a [ToolBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html)

Comment: @Elltz Sir, I feel if you have a better answer, then why not give it to the OP instead of down voting me because of my personal opinion. Did my opinion provoked you in some manner? It was for the OP, not for you.

Give your answer, let the OP decide what's better. Simple.

Comment: Sir, no, and i am not downvoting you based on your personal opinion or what you have to offer, but i think it is not a direct Answer to the question he asked, he was asking about a problem on `ActionBarSherlock` the answer is to give the solution to the problem not telling some features about ActionBar.. my downvote was because of that, and my pitch was not the solution.

Comment: @Elltz Ok. I understand, sir. Will remember it next time.